# Creating a related list on Opps pulling a custom object in the same format as the Contact Roles

Tags: custom-object, related-list, opportunitycontactrole

So I'm trying to create a related list on Opportunities that pulls a custom object called Technologies (an Object where we store Competitors info essentially).
So I've created a Custom Object that has the following:
[image: Competitor Custom Object]

I've added it to my Opportunities layout and it works.

Now my problem is that to make it better, I'd like to be able to add several "Competitors" at a time, very much like the Contact Roles and the Partner Roles related lists work. Unfortunately I can't find how they are set up (they seem hidden) to copy it.

This is how it looks now:
[image]

This is how I want it to be:
[image]

I hope this makes sense, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with standard functionality.  The Contact Role page type of functionality is not exposed for custom relationships.  There is now way to see how it is done (e.g., see code, etc.) You will have to create a [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce) page to do what you want to do.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I guess I need to get into Visualforce then! And so there's no way I can find a 'template' somewhere to get the general idea?

Comment: I don't know of one for this specific use.  There are workbooks on the [Salesforce Devs site](http://developers.salesforce.com) that do step through writing some code, but not this *specific* code.